# add dataitem(from string array) to listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, webforms

To preface this, I've looked through several of the postings containing listviews and nothing really is comparing to what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to take values determined through a loop that has several If Statements similar to what follows:

```
If Convert.ToInt32(GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_DAYS", DefaultValue)) > 0 Or _
           Convert.ToInt32(GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_HRS", DefaultValue)) > 0 Or _
           Convert.ToInt32(GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_MINS", DefaultValue)) > 0 Then
       msChargeDays = GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_DAYS", DefaultValue)
       msChargeHours = GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_HRS", DefaultValue)
       msChargeMins = GetData(ds.Tables("HRIS").Rows(i), "ABS_CO_RULE_MINS", DefaultValue)
       msHowPaid = "CR DAYS"
       AbsenceLine() 'calls sub
 End If
```

This block of code returns valid results from the dataset that it calls from.  Now in the following code block, I am trying to assimilate values that are determined by the main code block which is about 40 if statements similar in structure to the block above, all contained within a For loop.

In the following code block I am trying to insert an object of ListViewItem type into the ListView.  This is where I'm getting my error denoted by comment string following it.  The function that fills the ListViewItem is at the bottom, all of the variables returned are all class variables and return valid values to the ListViewItem.  I have double checked this via the debugger.

```
Private Sub AbsenceLine()

    Dim sTypeReason As String
    If msType = "" Then
        sTypeReason = Left(msReason, 25)
    Else
        sTypeReason = msType & "--" & msReason
    End If

    Dim item As ListViewItem
    item = New ListViewItem(ListViewItemType.DataItem)

    item.DataItem = FillListView(sTypeReason)

    absence_lv.Items.Add(item) 'this line here is what is givine me issues

 End Sub

 Private Function FillListView(typeReason As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)

    Return {msDate, msVoid, msCont, msDays, msHours, msMinutes, typeReason, msChargeDays, msChargeHours,
            msChargeMins, msHowPaid} 'all values returned are of String type
End Function
```

Now with the background:

Am I completely off base with what I'm trying to do?
Is there an easier way to do this with a gridview instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misusing the DataItem property of the ListViewItem class.  That's really used to get the underlying object that the ListViewItem represents when the ListView itself is bound.

Since your FillListView function is returning an IEnumerable(Of String), you can just set the ListView's DataSource property to the function call.

```
absence_lv.Datasource = FillListView(sTypeReason)
absence_lv.Databind()
```

As you can see, there is no need to manually add each item.

Comment: I had at first tried it that way and I kept on getting Null Reference Errors.  I figured out and alternate way to do it using a GridView that works just fine for what we are trying to do.